# clang compiler issue when trying to install scipy 1.6.1 on Apple Silicon MacOS

Tags: macos, cmake, apple-m1, apple-silicon

I'm trying to install scipy 1.6.1 as a dependency for a repository and I'm getting this issue during compilation:

`clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly`

I've tried updating cmake and installing gfortran and OpenBLAS via this [doc](http://scipy.github.io/devdocs/building/macosx.html) but I'm still getting compilation errors. I'm running on MacOS with Apple Silicon. Installing the latest version 1.8.0 seems to work, but I guess they don't have Mac ARM binaries for this version. Any idea what's causing this compilation error?

Comment: You've installed OpenBLAS, but haven't you forgotten to install environment variable like this: `OPENBLAS="$(brew --prefix openblas)" pip install scipy`

Comment: @flam3 Tried it and still the same error. According to my fish history I've tried this before too.

Answer (score 0):

I met the exact same issue before.  I just upgraded `scipy` from **1.6.1** to **1.9.1**, problem solved.  I hope it can help you.

My hardware is Macbook Air 2022, with an Apple Silicon(M2) chip in it.